# How to handle CloudFront Signed Cookie with .m3u8 files on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, avplayer

I have an App which is playing audio files stored on AWS.
The audio content is secured by AWS CloudFront signed cookies functionality. I had no problem in creating the signed cookies and set them in the original HTTP request using `AVURLAsset`, and everything works just fine for .mp3 content. Nevertheless, when accessing .m3u8 files, I get a 403 HTTP error. I noticed that the initial request is ok and the .m3u8 file is downloaded correctly, but the subsequent requests (for the audio fragments) do not work and receive a 403 as the cookie is not sent.

I already tried using the `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, but it did not work ;-(

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://..../stream.m3u8"]

// Get the Cookie Storage
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookiesStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

// Create the array to store the cookies
NSMutableArray *cookies = [NSMutableArray array];

// Create the Cloud-Front-Policy Cookie
NSHTTPCookie *cloudFrontPolicyCookie = ... 
[cookies addObject:cloudFrontPolicyCookie];

// Create the Cloud-Front-Signature Cookie
NSHTTPCookie *cloudFrontSignatureCookie = ... 
[cookies addObject:cloudFrontSignatureCookie];

// Create the Cloud-Front-Key-Paid-Id Cookie
NSHTTPCookie *cloudFrontKeyPairIdCookie = ... 
[cookies addObject:cloudFrontKeyPairIdCookie];

// Create the HTTP Header Dictionary
NSMutableDictionary * headers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// I omitted the cookie creation, but it is ok! I tested using curl on the command line 
NSString *cookieAsHeader = ... 

// Set the header
[headers setObject:cookieAsHeader forKey:@"Cookie"];

// Create the AVURLAsset so that I can use the headers and the cookies
// Notice that I tried using only the headers (which works)!
AVURLAsset * asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:@{@"AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers, AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey : [cookiesStorage cookies] }];

// For secured .mp3 files, it works just fine
// but for .m3u8, the content does not play as the first file part receives 403. Notice that the first request (for the .m3u8) works just fine. 
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
```

Comment: Notice that the code is on objective-c by I also tried with swift, but unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the cookies, unfortunately aws ios sdk doesn't have this function. My temporary solution for now is one the the following:

1) Ask web server to generate the cookies (using aws php sdk). In this way you can set timeout in a few minutes or anytime you desire, so you can keep the data safe.

2) Hardcoded the cookies inside the code. You can generate it locally using aws php sdk, and then set duration as long as possible. Maybe a year or more depend on your condition. However if someone can see it, your data will be exposed.

3) Create our own cookies generator function in swift/obj-c. We can use aws php sdk for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like would be a good way to handle it: https://github.com/ykying/Swift_Player_AWS_Cookie

You will likely need to generate the cookies on whatever server you have written for serving content and whenever the user opens the app or logs in, give them the cookies with a 24 hour expiration (or however long your current session TTL is).

I hope this helps someone else, we're going to try this out in our app as well.